# R: for loop to store multiple lm objects in a list

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lm

I am trying to store multiple lm objects in a single list. For instance, I fit 3 simple polynomials regressions of order 1, 2, 3 and add them to a list through a for loop.

```
lm_results <- list() 
for (i in 1:3){
  lm_results[[i]] <- lm(mpg~poly(horsepower, i), 
                        data=Auto)
}
```

There must be something wrong in what I do, cause the `predict()` function only works on the last object of the list, i.e. `lm_results[[3]]`

For `lm_results[[1]]`, I get an Error and a Warning messages:

```
predict(lm_results[[1]], Auto)

Error: variable 'poly(horsepower, i)' was fitted with type "nmatrix.2" but 
type "nmatrix.3" was supplied
In addition: Warning message:
In Z/rep(sqrt(norm2[-1L]), each = length(x)) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

For `lm_results[[2]]`, only the Warning message shows up:

```
predict(lm_results[[2]], Auto)

Error: variable 'poly(horsepower, i)' was fitted with type "nmatrix.1" but 
type "nmatrix.3" was supplied
```

The weirdest thing is that if I do the same "manually" (see below), everything works fine.

```
lm_results <- list()
lm_results[[1]] <- lm(mpg~poly(horsepower, 1), 
                  data=Auto)
lm_results[[2]] <- lm(mpg~poly(horsepower, 2), 
                  data=Auto)
lm_results[[3]] <- lm(mpg~poly(horsepower, 3), 
                  data=Auto)
```

Any idea of what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using `lapply` instead solves the problem for me:

```
lm_results <- lapply(1:3, function(x) lm(mpg ~ poly(horsepower, x), data = Auto))
```